# Getting callback in a service in dependency module from a fragment in app module

Tags: android, kotlin, interface, callback, circular-dependency

I have 2 modules, 1 is my application and another module which is added as a dependency to my app module. App module consist of Fragment A and the dependency module has a service in it. I want to do some action in the service class, if the Fragment A in my app module got destroyed. How can I get a callback in my service from the fragment onDestroy() method? I tried using interface, but caused circular dependency problem.
Note : I  want the callback to be received in the class in a module which is added as a dependency to the app.
Any suggestion are appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to post what you've got that requires a circular dependency - but generally speaking, when you split an app into a hierarchy of modules, the lower ones shouldn't know anything about the modules higher up in the tree. So if you need two-way communication between the `Fragment` and the `Service`, you can create an interface in the lower module (the one that's a dependency of the other). That way the upper one can implement that interface, and the lower one doesn't need to know anything about the upper one. (Or you could put the interface in a separate "utility" module dependency)

Comment: @cactustictacs, I want to get the call back on on the lower one. " FragementA" in higher module and "ServiceB" in lower one. I need to get a callback on "ServiceB" when "FragmentA" onDestroy() got called. As you mentioned, I can create an interface in the "serviceB" and implement it in "fragmentA". But how can I get call back to serviceB?

Comment: ``fragmentModule`` has a dependency on ``serviceModule``, right? So it knows all about ``serviceModule`` and all the classes and interfaces in there, it knows what ``YourService`` is. So it can create the instance of that service that you're using, and you can communicate with it in the usual ways (e.g.: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Binder). The only difference the separate module makes is that ``serviceModule`` isn't aware of ``fragmentModule``, so it can't reference any of its classes, public methods etc. That's why you need an interface in ``serviceModule``